# How to access variable in puppet

Tags: configuration, puppet

I've written a module and I've defined a variable called "master" in the location:
/etc/puppet/network/manifests/vlan/vlan.pp. In vlan.pp I make a call to a template file:
    file { "ifcfg-${interface}":
       content => template('net/vlan.erb'),
    }
However I can't access the variable "master" in the file location:

/etc/puppet/modules/net/templates/vlan.erb

When puppet runs on the client it doesn't get printed. My understanding would be this is a scope issue, but I'm stuck as to what the scope call should be, can someone please help me with this?

I've tried the following calls already in the erb file:
    <%= scope.lookupvar('network::vlan::master') %>
    <%= scope.lookupvar('network::vlan::vlan::master') %>
    <%= master %>

Thanks
Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change your template to have something like:

```
<%= @master %>
```

Also make sure that in your vlan.pp you have something of the sort:

```
$master = "value"
```

The template will have whatever variables are accessible in the scope of where the template was generated.  An easy way to make sure a variable is accessible in the template is to turn any variables from outside the local scope into an instance variable with something like this:

```
$var = $somemodule::var
```

Then you access the var in your template with @var.

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for the reply I am setting the variable in my nodes.pp by calling the following:

 net::vlan::vlan { "vlan1":
                master          => "bond0",        }

Then in vlan.pp I do the following:

    define net::vlan::vlan (
      $master,
    ) {
    ...
    Then in my code I call a file resource with the line:
    content => template('network/ifcfg-vlan.erb'),
   }


which file should I put your suggestion in? i.e the point about:
$var = $somemodule::var

Thanks again
Dan

Comment: Maybe as a test, add to `net::vlan::vlan ($master) { $local_master = $master`, then use `@local_master` in your template, see if it isn't seeing the variable master properly.